# Data binding to an XmlDataProvider in XAML not displaying data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to make a very simple `ListBox` view that shows items from a short list as labels. However, the window pops up blank. XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReCheckList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReCheckList"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="298" Width="192">
<Window.Resources>
<!----- Data Source ---------->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="PackingListDataSource" XPath="cList">
        <x:XData>
            <Checklist xmlns="">
                <ListNode Title="Socks"/>
                <ListNode Title="Shoes"/>
                <ListNode Title="Toothbrush"/>
            </Checklist>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
<!--- Data Template ----------->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListNodeTemplate">
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Title}"></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<!------ ListBox ------->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PackingListDataSource}, XPath=ListNode}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListNodeTemplate}">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

What is wrong with my data bindings?

---

**EDIT:** The most fundamental error was that the `XPath` of the `XmlDataProvider` did not match the root node of the xml data. Changing that to `"Checklist"` was the simplest fix, not requiring modifying my `XPath` search parameters.

Comment: What does the ListNodeTemplate look like? Can it display the ItemsSource data?

Comment: your `cList` doesn't make any sense

Comment: The code example I was looking at, the ExpenseIt tutorial on the WPF docs, had an `XPath` in the `XmlProvider`, so I added one in mine. I wasn't sure what to call it, or what it does, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `XPath` attribute from the `XmlDataProvider`

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="PackingListDataSource">
    <x:XData>
        <Checklist xmlns="">
            <ListNode Title="Socks"/>
            <ListNode Title="Shoes"/>
            <ListNode Title="Toothbrush"/>
        </Checklist>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

Then, fix the `XPath` in the `ItemsSource` binding so it returns all ListNodes in the XML. In practice you might want to narrow it down more, but this at least gets me items in the `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PackingListDataSource}, XPath='//ListNode'}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListNodeTemplate}"
    >
</ListBox>
```

`//` means "Search the whole XML tree for any element with this name". Leaving that out, you're only searching the element you're looking at for anything with that name. In this case, you're looking at the root. You could explicitly start the path at root by prefacing the path with a single slash: `/CheckList/ListNode`.

Alternatively (I'm learning as I go here), you could leave the binding XPath as you had it, and just change the `XPath` attribute of the `XmlDataProvider` to `Checklist`, so your binding will look in `Checklist` for `ListNode` elements. Your problem was really just that `cList` was wrong for that `XPath` attribute because you don't have anything called `cList` at the root of your XML.

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="PackingListDataSource" XPath="Checklist">
    <x:XData>
        <Checklist xmlns="" Title="Foo">
            <ListNode Title="Socks"/>
            <ListNode Title="Shoes"/>
            <ListNode Title="Toothbrush"/>
        </Checklist>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>

...

<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PackingListDataSource}, XPath='ListNode'}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListNodeTemplate}"
    >
</ListBox>
```

Remember that XML is case sensitive, so `Checklist` is not `CheckList`. And when I say you need to remember that, I really mean that I forgot it.

Comment: I'm not sure how `XPath` works. How does adding `//` change the binding?

Comment: @mooglinux `//` means "search the whole tree for anything with this name". Leaving that out, you're just searching the root item for children with that name. I've been playing with this, and I'm going to update my answer with  more detail.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I think you might need `/` to actually access the root, `Name` should be an alias for `./Name` which is relative. (So the question is whether that is implicitly relative to the root.)

Comment: @H.B. Yes, of course. In this case it happens to be looking relative to the root, so `Name`/`./Name` works, that's all. I struggled with how to express the distinction and gave in to expediency/laziness.

Comment: Changing the `XPath` of the `XmlDataProvider` looks like the most straightforward solution here, since I intend to start nesting data soon.

Comment: @mooglinux I agree.

Answer (score 1):

`ListNode` seems just like the wrong XPath here, did you mean `//ListNode` or `/Checklist/ListNode`? Also, you set an `XPath` on the provider that does not appear in the data, would remove that.

Comment: I'm not sure how XPath works. How does adding `//` change the binding?

Comment: If you don't know that you should be learning about XPath before using it. `//` finds all elements in the tree with a given name/filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- change the XPath to "Checklist" -->
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="PackingListDataSource" XPath="cList">
    <x:XData>
        <Checklist xmlns="">
            <ListNode Title="Socks"/>
            <ListNode Title="Shoes"/>
            <ListNode Title="Toothbrush"/>
        </Checklist>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

Comment: The change you have to do is noted in the comment : change the XPath to "Checklist".